# Docker Login is Succeeded but no pull or push are denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, ubuntu-18.04

When I'm trying to pull or push images from container Container Registry on github.com.

Upon inspection I noticed that `.docker/config.json` is not saving docker login credentials

```
$ docker login registry.gitlab.com -u [username]
Password:
Login Succeeded

$ cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.gitlab.com": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "pass"
}
```

I'm also using docker-credential-helpers.
My Ubuntu version

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Were you expecting the config.json to have credentials with the credential helper configured?

Comment: @BMitch, so credential helper configured is a substitution for config.json. I see passwords that I type added to helper, but for some reason it's not being used? How can I test it? Why do I get denied access then?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to determine a clear root cause, but here are some facts on the issue that may help others.

- https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/158 : It is an issue faced by many others, and as usual many people found many different solutions that worked for them.
- It is definitely an issue with the credsStore configuration. I was able to authenticate before setting up a credential helper, but not afterwards. Some people were able to uninstall and normal authentication worked again.
- It seems to be an issue related to the passphrase on the gpg key not being handled properly by the credential helper.
- One potential solution, `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` which explicitly tells GPG where to ask for the passphrase may work by allowing the passphrase prompt to reach the terminal.
- Another potential solution, which worked for me, involves setting the passphrase expiration to two years, then manually providing the passphrase, which may work because the credential helper no longer needs to ask for the passphrase (for two years). Here are the steps for that workaround:

1. Assuming you already have `pass` installed, `docker-credential-helpers` setup, and a gpg key created...
2. Set the gpg passphrase timeout to 2 years...

```
echo "default-cache-ttl 62208000" > ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
echo "max-cache-ttl 62208000" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

3. Restart the gpg agent: `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`
4. Execute `pass show docker-credential-helpers` which should give you a credential list tree similar to:

```
docker-credential-helpers
└── Na4unc0Om0clab202nyjkdunWDK=
    └── itsme
```

5. Execute `pass show docker-credential-helpers/Na4unc0Om0clab202nyjkdunWDK=/itsme` based on the above output. This will ask for your passphrase.

You should then be able to complete docker pull/push commands. If neither of the above solutions work for you, feel free to read the thread for more options and share here what works.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the issue by executing

`export GPG_TTY=(tty)`

idea came from this post https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/158#issuecomment-516996013

I don't understand how it works and why. If someone could explain it would be appreciated.